# How to shift bits in hexdump

Tags: hexdump

I'm trying to visualize the bitmap of a frame buffer using hexdump, however the data is shifted left by two. Is it possible to use the hexdump (or other binary file visualization tool like xxd) formatting to shift each byte right by two for visualization?

Example:

My current file:

0x84 0x14 0x50

I want to see (each byte shifted right by two):

0x21 0x05 0x14

Comment: What is your operating system and which hexdump product do you use?

Comment: It is the standard hexdump that you can find in most Linux distributions, at least as a downloadable package. However, I'm not stuck to any specific tool, if this solution can be done using other package, I will accept as an answer.